# What is file ']' ? How is it created?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I wonder how this file got in my directory? When I run `ls -lrt` it shows `-rw-r--r-- 1` and size `117562` . Can I get any directions for this?

Comment: Most probably a programming error. Some scripts invoke the program `[` (`test`). See `man test`.

Comment: What is the full path of `]` file? What does `file ]` say?

Comment: Check the contents

Comment: @Grzegorz It says
`]: makefile script, ASCII text, with very long lines`

Comment: @OliverSalzburg When I try to check contents,it says
`ls: cannot access ]/: Not a directory`

Comment: @Arya Well, it's a file, not a directory. So you can't use `ls` on it. Try `less`.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I got.I can read it using `vim`.Its a script.But I think it is generated automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see that is going on, in your case I would do

```
$ ls -l ]?  
$ ls | od -x
```

You can create a file will any ASCII char (`man 7 ascii`) in unix. Almost always they are created by accident. Sometimes there is a trailing char in a file.

```
$ ls | od -x   # to find out.
```

I usually carefully remove them with ? since ? matches 1 char. First ls ? to see what is matches, then `rm ?` Or if there is a weird trailing char to a file then `<wierdfile?>`

There was a trick to make a file with the BEL ASCII code (07), so then when you did a `ls`, you would hear a sound.

```
$ touch `echo -e "\a"`   # \a is BEL 
$ ls # the filename is not really ?, it is really the BEL sign (07)
?

$ ls | od -x   # see that it is 07

0000000 0a07
0000002

$ ls ? #  ? with match any file with 1 char.
?
$ rm ?  # just 1 file so safe to run it.
```

or interactive for even safer removal.

```
$ rm -i ?
```

rm: remove regular empty file ‘\a’? y

```
$ ls ?
ls: cannot access ?: No such file or directory
```

Yep file is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Some faulty script could to that. You can delete it with

```
rm -vf ']'
```